# How to give each GridView Headers inside the Repeater a different color?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, repeater

I have a `Repeater` and three `GridView`s inside the `Repeater`. Each `GridView` has different columns than the others since I have a stored procedure and each `GridView` has different columns based on the value of a `HiddenField` inside the repeater.

Now, I would like to give each `GridView` a different color, especially for the columns that are different in each `GridView`.

How would I do this?

Comment: I assume that these `GridView`s share **some** columns. Can you post the column names that you expect each stored procedure to return?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use the OnItemCreated event on the repeater and then grab the GV and the HiddenField through the Controls collection and do whatever you want with them.

However, I wouldn't use a repeater for outputting stuff that isn't alike. If the gridviews are that much different, what is the point of the repeater? Why not just make three seperate gridviews?